# JSON data filtering using javaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have assigned a task to group data in angular js using underscore js.

My JSON :

```
 data = [   
        {
          "Building*": "Building A",
          "Wing*": "Wing C",
          "Floor*": "Floor 3",
          "Room Name*": "Room 3",
          "Room Type*": "AC",
          "Location*": "Location 1",
          "Device ID*": 27,
          "Category*": "Soap Hygene",
          "Dispenser Name*": "Dispenser 34",
          "Type*": "Manual",
          "Cartridge Type*": "Type 1",
          "Date of installation": "2016-04-11T06:06:22 -06:-30",
          "Contact Last Name": "Maynard",
          "Email Address": "thomas.boscher@gmail.com",
          "Mobile Number with country code": "+1 (949) 590-3465",
          "Description": "Description of device",
          "Model": 37
        },
        {
          "Building*": "Building B",
          "Wing*": "Wing B",
          "Floor*": "Floor 3",
          "Room Name*": "Room 1",
          "Room Type*": "AC",
          "Location*": "Location 3",
          "Device ID*": 26,
          "Category*": "Soap Hygene",
          "Dispenser Name*": "Dispenser 33",
          "Type*": "Manual",
          "Cartridge Type*": "Type 2",
          "Date of installation": "2015-07-24T12:42:24 -06:-30",
          "Contact Last Name": "Holland",
          "Email Address": "thomas.boscher@gmail.com",
          "Mobile Number with country code": "+1 (947) 491-2353",
          "Description": "Description of device",
          "Model": 32
        }         

      ]
```

**I need data in below format, where it has each building details containing the wing and floor data**

```
  updateData = [{ 
    building: 'Building A' , 
    buildingData:[ {
        wing: "Wing A",
         wingData: [{
          floor:'Floor 2',
          floorData:[{
            room:'Room 3',
            roomData:[]
            }]
          }]
        }]
  }];
```

I tried :

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvsbharat/t6216usc/)

But it fails. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How `wing` comes under `buildingData` ? It should be `wind->building->floor->room` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to groupBy in the following nested order:

Building ->> Wing ->> Floor ->> Room

You can try calling groupBy recursively (or looping through, up to you) by passing an array of the order of nested attribute you want to groupBy. Try this snippet below:

```
const nestedOrder = ['Building*', 'Wing*', 'Floor*', 'Room Name*']

function groupFilter (rawData, attrList) {
  if (attrList.length == 0) return rawData

  var currentAttr = _(attrList).first()
  return _(rawData)
    .chain()
    .groupBy(currentAttr)
    .map((list, attrName) => Object({
      [currentAttr]: attrName,
      [`${currentAttr}Data`]: groupFilter(list, _(attrList).rest())
    }))
    .value()
}

console.log(groupFilter(data, nestedOrder))
```

The raw data will then be compacted to the deepest nested attribute, in this case 'Room Name*', you can then write your custom filter to output what you want RoomData to hold.

Not sure if its the right way to do it, but if runtime isnt a big issue for you then I think you can make it work fine.

Hopefully this helps/works out for you.